# sql query validator

Tags: sql, apache-flex, validation

Is there any sql query validator in frontend side or in any language for validating the query syntax before executing in the database ?.In my current project i have to validate the the sql query in flex before it goes to back end ,coz it has to pass lot many layers before hitting database and the hitting the DB and coming back with an exception is an too expensive process .So im in need of sql query validator in front end side to atleast say its a valid query .

Comment: Any specific database in mind? SQL that is valid in one database may not be valid in another.

Comment: no..we have to support all the DBs.

Comment: Is your SQL static (or limited in parameters), or dynamic?

If it's static, you can evaluate during project development (presumably that's ok?).

If it's dynamic, you'd need a plugin inside your app to validate it before sending it to (possibly) multiple types of DB (if I read you right). That sounds like a rather lopsided solution.

Comment: it is dynamic .But wont be too complex select query with where clauses and joins .thts all .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the [SQL BNF grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/) and use [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#Software_using_BNF) to validate input.

I am sure you would have to tweak the standard grammar and this is not trivial.
Also, I am sure that you can find something better, but I hope the above will get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Parsing at runtime you can look at:
SQL4J is a SQL-parser written in Java.
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jglu/sql4j/index.htm

http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/

Perhaps you can use Antlr, it has a number of SQL grammars.
http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list

Or as advised, use the parser of open source SQL utilities like SQuirreL SQL Client.
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

or use parts of an open source pure Java DBMS like SmallSQL.
http://www.smallsql.de/

There is Eclipse IDE plugins for validating SQL from IDE.

Check out: 
http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/

Comment: but those i can jus validate once tht too by user intervention .My requirement is tht i will generating a query from flex using using the help of user by clicking button or some actions .That generated query should be validated syntactically over there itself through a piece of code .

Comment: @Bhaswanth so you generate query dynamically ? isn't it a query and you just pass criteria or values selected by user to query ?

Comment: @YoK, as far as I can understand he is using it as a debugging tool/exception handler.

Comment: @Yok : similar to the concept of criteria .But not exactly the same .Let us think user directly wrote a query and i need to validate it in front end before gng backend .

Comment: @Bhaswanth I have added few parsers and validator links to my answer. Hope these help.

Comment: @Bhaswanth, feel free to upvote answers that are helpfull; see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Unreason :sure .Im a newbee to this .Jus learning the way to act .Thanks for the info .